# A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces, for using UnityEngine. Transform;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

// hello i get this error when i run this code:   Assets\Scripts\enemy.cs(4,7): error CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Transform' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Transform;
                             
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform [] waypoints;
    public Transform [] target;
    private int destPoint=0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        target = waypoints[0];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir=target.position - Transform.position;
        Transform . Translate(dir.normalized * speed* Time.deltaTime, Space . World);

        if(Vector3.Distance(Transform.position, target.position) <0.3f)
        {
            destPoint = (destPoint + 1)   % waypoints.Length ; 
            target = waypoints[destPoint];     
             }
        
    }
}
```

// Thanks

```
//if I delete using UnityEngine.Transform; there will be a lot of errors :
```

.cs(18,18): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Transform[]

.cs(24,28): error CS1061: 'Transform[]' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

cs(24,39): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.position'

.cs(25,9): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.Translate(Vector3, Space)'

cs(27,29): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.position'

cs(27,56): error CS1061: 'Transform[]' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

cs(30,22): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Transform[]'

Comment: Delete this line: `using UnityEngine.Transform;` You don't need it. Looks like you have some other errors where you try to use the type `Transform` as a variable too.

Comment: `target = waypoints[destPoint];` is your problem: `target` is an array of `Transform`, `waypoints[destPoint]` is a `Transform`, you can't assign one to the other. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

it is because Transform is a class and not a namespace inside the UnityEngine namespace, so you should just remove the using UnityEngine.Transform; and keep everything else the same.

Comment: yes but the problem after there is a lot of error.

Comment: what error does it give afterwards?

Comment: Assets\Scripts\ennemy.cs(18,18): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Transform[]'.              OR         .cs(24,28): error CS1061: 'Transform[]' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)              OR           cs(24,39): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.position'      and many more

Comment: ```Transform.position``` is not posible you'll have to use ```targetObject.transform.position```